# Unicode font is not rendering in SWING when combine three characters ക (\u0D15) + ് (\u0D4D) + ര (\u0D30), getting ര്ക instead of ക്ര

Tags: java, swing, unicode, fonts, editor

I am working on a text editor for Malayalam in Java.

Unicode font is not rendering correctly in Swing - `JTextArea`.
Combination of characters. Instead of blending two characters, Text area displaying it separately. Both swing and font support those characters but in key combinations it is not working Even though supported font is used. 
For Example:

### What is needed

```
ക്രാ
```

### What is getting

```
്രക
```

### Code

```
jButton69.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Meera", 0, 12)); // NOI18N
        jButton69.setText(" ്ര");

    jTextArea1.append(jButton69.getText());
```

EDIT: (Complementary information from author's commentary):

When combine three characters ക (\u0D15) + ് (\u0D4D) + ര (\u0D30), I am getting ര്ക instead of ക്ര.

Language is Malayalam, Font is Meera

Comment: It's going to be very difficult for anyone to help you with the limited information you've provided here.  Example code snippets, screenshots, and more context as to what you're trying to do vs. what you're seeing will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: just in case, have you tried changing the font family?

Comment: Note that one line of code is not an SSCCE.

Comment: Are you expecting to get a string transformation from concatenating 2 strings? I'm afraid that has nothing to do with Swing or you are chasing 2 different goals here.

Comment: I think you are talking about literals interpretation, how could java know that the concatenation of several unicode chars would result in several different ones? If your browser does it and your XP does it too it's because they have some API that is doing that interpretation.

Comment: @PbxMan  That part is managed by Unicode font 
for example ക + symbol[ൂ] gives കൂ .  It is automatically transformed

Comment: @karu it's how it think it worked and I haven't seen anything to the contrary. ex. If I were to put the symbols "ക" + "[ൂ" in a web page html with no spaces between them encoded in UTF-8 I would see കൂ  ?
I wanna help you but it's getting hard for me to test.

Comment: @PbxMan All other symbols are working only error is occurring in the case of[ ്ര] only one symbol.

Comment: OK I'm afraid I cannot help you, good luck!

Comment: @PbxMan Thank you very much. Could you please tell me how java process fonts?

Comment: Dude I had the same issue, I tried to load fonts directly(not from os) by `FOnt#createFont()` and the problem solved. @karu

Answer (score 0):

You must set the JTextArea font to a Unicode font.

Besides that, the button69 has nothing to do with the problem, so I don't use it.

The following code is showing the text the way you want:

```
String problemText = "ഔ";
Font font = new Font("Arial Unicode MS", Font.PLAIN, 18);
JTextArea jTextArea1 = new JTextArea();
jTextArea1.setFont(font);
jTextArea1.append(problemText);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Nice! If it helped, feel free to upvote and mark as answered.

Comment: I thought your problem was solved. What else can I do to help you?

Comment: Hi @pablosaraiva,   I am using Using JTextArea for editor.   When  combine three characters ക + ് + ര, I am getting ര്ക instead of ക്ര. Font used is Meera or any Unicode font. Language is Malayalam in Ubuntu it is working fine but in Windows XP it is not working. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Windows XP SP2? Something I have found here: http://www.alanwood.net/unicode/malayalam.html - Microsoft Windows incorporates support for Malayalam Unicode from Windows XP SP2 onwards.

Comment: When I hit ക, ്, ര it changes to ര ് ക when it should be ക്ര. It works fine on microsoft word but fails on Java. I'm using the Kartika font. I'm still trying to help.

Comment: Even the web browser renders it right. It really looks like a bug.

Comment: Yes, You are right. In any text editor it will work but in Java Based ones it won't . I am using Windows Xp SP3.  But I not getting any idea  why this error. In Ubuntu and other Linux version it is working perfectly. I am using Unicode 6.2 for my purpose. you could download meera font from here https://code.google.com/p/naaraayam/downloads/detail?name=Meera.ttf

Comment: Arial Unicode MS is a fallback font with very poor script support (it supports plenty of glyphs, but that's about it – there is little to no information in the font of how to properly use those glyphs in scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Zero Width Joiners and Zero Width Non-joiners. For your requirement, I got the correct output by using a zero width joiner as: \u0d15 + \u0d4d + \u200d + \u0d30.

Answer (score 0):

Please check out Zero Width Joiners and Zero Width Non-joiners. For your requirement, I got the correct output by using a zero width joiner as: \u0d15 + \u0d4d + \u200d + \u0d30 (Please ignore my previous answer, it is the same but posted with the wrong user account).